# How to get the 'real' creator of an uploaded file using Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am developing a Teams personal app and I have to filter the files by creator.

There is an entry point to get DriveItem:

/dirves/<driveId>/items/<itemId>

The createdBy field of DriveItem should contain info about the creator, uploader.

But if I upload a file with 'Upload' menu of Files tab of Teams Web App then the createdBy field contains a reference to the creator of the team instead of me.
If I upload files with Teams Desktop App or Teams Mobile App then createdBy field references to me.

Which field of driveItem object contans the real creator/uploader of the file?
Or which Graph API entry point gives back the real creator/uploader of a file?

Comment: Apologies for the delay we tried this at our end and createdby in /dirves/<driveId>/items/<itemId> gives the uploader name only. We tried uploading files from both Desktop and Web client. It gives correct details in both cases.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGbHu.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/D69Pj.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/I76fB.png.

Please note that team is created by a different user.

Comment: Can you please share if you are doing it differently so that we can try it from our end.